# On the closure of the union of an increasing sequence of compact sets.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $K_1\subset K_2\subset...\subset K_n\subset K_{n+1}\subset....$ be a sequence of compact sets in some metric space $(X,d)$. Suppose that $K_n\subset B$ for all $n$ for some bounded set $B$.

Under what conditions would $cl\bigcup_nK_n $ (where $cl A$ means closure of a set $A$) be itself a compact set?

The answer is trivial for the so called 'proper' metric spaces (metric spaces where every closed ball is compact). It follows by definition that any bounded and closed set is compact in a proper metric space. I am interested in the non-proper case. Any suggestions or directions are appreciated.

Comment: What is a non-proper metric space (or a proper metric space)?  I have never heard the term proper used for metric spaces.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: Apparently $\langle X,d\rangle$ is proper if $\{y\in X:d(x,y)\le r\}$ is compact for each $x\in X$ and $r>0$.

Comment: Do you want conditions on the metric space or conditions on the sequence of compact sets?

Comment: In a **separable** metric space, **every** closed set is the closure of the union of an increasing sequence of compact (in fact finite) sets. So in the case of a separable metric space, you are asking, under what conditions is a bounded closed set compact?

Comment: In general, if $K$ is a subset of a metric space, then $K$ is the closure of the union of an increasing sequence of compact subsets of a bounded set if and only if $K$ is closed, bounded, and separable. So your question is equivalent to asking, under what conditions a closed bounded separable subset of a metric space is compact. What sort of conditions did you have in mind??

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for.  As you noted the statement is not true for infinite dimensional metric spaces.  Each $K_n$ could be a closed ball in an $n-$dimensional subspace (compact), but the limit closed ball  $(\infty$ limit) is not compact.

Comment: @bof I would be interested more on additional conditions on the sequence of sets $K_n$ when the underlying metric space is for example non-locally compact and complete. Also the question you raised for separable bounded subsets is helpful.